# Set up a crosswalk cordova environment for both AMD and x86

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime

So, I have a neat setup running that generates me AMD `.apk`'s, however the android AMD emulator is incredibly slow unlike the x86 hardware accelerated emulator. Using standard crosswalk you automatically generate both an `.apk` for the AMD and the x86 platform, is there any way to achieve the same thing with the Cordova Crosswalk libraries *without* having two entirely separate code bases/projects besides each other.